# Monkeypatching sqlserver adapter to support higher versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I never had to monkeypatch a gem before. I temporarily need to patch the sqlserver adapter gem to support 2016 lower version of rails.

So, i ended up making the change on this file:
gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.24/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb

```
  SUPPORTED_VERSIONS          = [2000,2005,2008,2016].freeze

  def sqlserver_2016?
    @database_year == 2016
  end
```

My question, how do I make this a code change in my app instead of updating the file under gems directory?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I think you are going to find that this will cause more issues than it solves. Also you should immediately consider updating rails (and the adapter along with it) as 2.3 reached EOL more than 6 years ago.

Comment: that depends on the actual implementation within sqlserver_adapter.rb i guess it's this version? https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/2.3.24/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb